# get postID from last row of tableview to form url argument for loading more

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to use [svpulltorefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh) for an app. I am populating a tableview with posts (with unique postID) I fetch from a server. How can I access the postID from the last row , so that everytime user pulls to refresh, this post ID can be sent back to server and  posts with IDs  older than this ID fetched?

I include the postID in a UILabel (hidden) in each cell

Comment: Why are you adding a hidden label to each cell? You should store the value in the data used by your table's data source.

Comment: surely you store the objects in your dataSource? so cant you do `[[self.dataSource lastObject] postID]`

Comment: @OliverAtkinson yes offcourse. Got it. Thank you!

Comment: @aVC I created an answer so others who have the same problem can easily find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the last object from the dataSource

```
[[self.dataSource lastObject] postID]
```